# Adding a parent user in the user model in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I've read a few posts on inheritance of the User model for *other models* in Django, but I want a user to have a particular parent user, i.e. the User model inherits itself.

I'm not sure how to do this as I'd surely have to edit the django.auth.contrib model for User wouldn't I?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't edit the source code in Django. That's a big mistake it'll make your code horrible to maintain - Whatever you're trying to do, you really don't want to change the Django source.

I'm not completely clear what you're asking, but it sound like you might need to create a new model that inherits from `User` and add a `ManyToMany` field to self on your model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ExtendedUser(User):
    parent = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
```

Your new model will now have all the fields and methods of Django's `User` class plus your extra `parent` field. The parent field on any particular `ExtendedUser` object will reference another `ExtendedUser` object.

As I say I'm taking a guess at what it is you're trying to do (If I've got it right, then you might find it helpful to do a bit of reading on [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) and [class inheritance](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) in general - maybe seek out a few tutorials on the subject too)